# Apply a function on a list of list using PySpark

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to apply a function on my df. My variable is a list of list, for each of them I would apply my function, in order to obtain a list of results for each of them.

```
dff = spark.createDataFrame([
('a', [[1,2,3,4], [1,1,2,3], [3,5,9,6], [12,4,2,2]]), 
('b', [[4,0.2,0.3,0.7],[1,1,1,1],[2,7,5,9]]), 
('c', [[1,1,2,9],[2,5,4,8],[5,7,4,8],[1,2,3,4],[4,4,4,6]]),
('d' ,[[2,2,2,2],[4,8,5,9],[1,5,9,6]])], ['num','list_apply'])
```

Thus I wrote this function, I registered it but I'm not able to find any results, only errors raised.

```
def calc(data):
  a,b,c,d = data
  dist = a+b+c*d
  if dist < 10:
    return True
  else:
    return False
  
calc_udf = f.udf(lambda x: calc(x), ArrayType(BooleanType()))
spark.udf.register("calc_udf", calc, T.ArrayType(T.BooleanType()))

dff = dff.withColumn("dist", f.expr("TRANSFORM(list_apply, x -> calc_udf(x))"))
```

What I want to obtain is:

```
+-----+------------+-------------------------------------+
| num | list_apply |                 dist                |
+-----+------------+-------------------------------------+
| a   |    ...     | [False, True, False, False]         |
| b   |    ...     | [True, True, False]                 |
| c   |    ...     | [False, False, False, False, False] |
| d   |    ...     | [True, False, False]                |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your approach is that in `transform` function, you are using a udf to take a list as an argument, which wouldn't work since a udf is supposed to take a Column (or Column name) as an argument. You can modify `calc_udf` take a list type column as follows and then directly use it on the `list_apply` column:

```
# instead of calc(x) we iterate through lst so we don't need transform
calc_udf = f.udf(lambda lst: [calc(x) for x in lst], ArrayType(BooleanType()))
dff = dff.withColumn("dist", calc_udf("list_apply"))

dff.show()
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
|num|          list_apply|                dist|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
|  a|[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, ...|[false, true, fal...|
|  b|[[4.0, 0.2, 0.3, ...| [true, true, false]|
|  c|[[1.0, 1.0, 2.0, ...|[false, false, fa...|
|  d|[[2.0, 2.0, 2.0, ...|[true, false, false]|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help,  I thought that the ```transform``` function would take every element of the main list in every row.

Comment: Do you know how I could modify my function to take this list of list, in order to obtain in the end a single value, i.e. taking the ```max()``` of of the complete list of results ? Here it's taking element per element, applies the function, and return a list of results. Is it possible to give it the complete list ```[1,2,3,4], [1,1,2,3]...```, get the max of ```a+b+c*d``` and return a single ```True``` or ```False``` ? Like this the ```transform()``` function could be applied ?